# Redis as a Queue - Bulk Retrieval

Tags: python, redis, scaling

Our Python application serves around 2 million API requests per day. We got a new requirement from our business to generate the report which should contain the count of unique request and response every day.

- We would like to use Redis for queuing all the requests &  responses.
- Another worker instance will retrieve the above data from Redis queue and process it.
- The processed results will be persisted to the database.

The simplest option is to use LPUSH and RPOP. But RPOP will return one value at a time which will affect the performance. Is there any way to do a bulk pop from Redis?

Other suggestions for the scenario would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You probably should use some lua scripting (http://redis.io/commands/eval) to execute multiple RPOP and return the removed data

Comment: use lrange; r.lrange("requests", 0, -1), will return the entire list, llen will retun length, lindex to get element at specific index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can approach this from a different angle. Your requirement is:

> > requirement ... to generate the report which should contain the count of unique request and response every day.

Rather than storing requests in the lists and then post-processing the results, why not use Redis features to solve the actual requirements and avoid the problem of bulk LPUSH/LPOP.

If all we want if to record the *unique counts*, then you may want to consider using *sorted sets*.

This may go like this:

#### Collect the request statistics

```
# Collect the request statistics in the sorted set.
# The key includes date so we can do the "by date" stats.
key = 'requests:date'
r.zincrby(key, request, 1)
```

#### Report request statistics

- Can use ZSCAN to iterate over all members in batches, but this is unordered.
- Can use ZRANGE to get all members in one go (or whatever), ordered.

Python code:

```
# ZSCAN: Iterate over all members in the set in batches of about 10.
# This will be unordered list.
# zscan_iter returns tuples (member, score)
batchSize = 10
for memberTuple in r.zscan_iter(key, match = None, count = batchSize):
    member = memberTuple[0]
    score = memberTuple[1]
    print str(member) + ' --> ' + str(score)


# ZRANGE: Get all members in the set, ordered by score.
# Here there maxRank=-1 means "no max".
minRank = 0
maxRank = -1
for memberTuple in r.zrange(key, minRank, maxRank, desc = False, withscores = True):
    member = memberTuple[0]
    score = memberTuple[1]
    print str(member) + ' --> ' + str(score)
```

#### Benefits of this approach

1. Solves the actual requirement - reports on the count of unique requests by day.
2. No need to post-process anything.
3. Can do additional queries like "top requests" out of the box :)

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution would be to use [redis pipelining](http://redis.io/topics/pipelining)

In a single request you will be allowed to perform multiple RPOP instructions.
Most of redis drivers support it. In python with [Redis-py](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py) it looks like this:

```
pipe = r.pipeline()
# The following RPOP commands are buffered
pipe.rpop('requests')
pipe.rpop('requests')
pipe.rpop('requests')
pipe.rpop('requests')
# the EXECUTE call sends all buffered commands to the server, returning
# a list of responses, one for each command.
pipe.execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use the [Hyperloglog data structure](http://redis.io/commands/pfadd).
It was [especially designed for this kind of use case](http://antirez.com/news/75).

It allows counting unique items with a low error margin (0.81%) and with a very low memory usage.

Using HLL is really simple:

```
PFADD myHll "<request1>"
PFADD myHll "<request2>"
PFADD myHll "<request3>"
PFADD myHll "<request4>"
```

Then to get the count:

```
PFCOUNT myHll
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual question was regarding Redis List, You can use lrange to get all values in a single call, below is solution;

```
import redis
r_server = redis.Redis("localhost")
r_server.rpush("requests", "Adam")
r_server.rpush("requests", "Bob")
r_server.rpush("requests", "Carol")

print r_server.lrange("requests", 0, -1)
print r_server.llen("requests")
print r_server.lindex("requests", 1)
```